# my java swing application jcomponents won't either paint, repaint only after calculations done?

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, imageicon, invokelater

i have a voice recognition system, this is the `listen(button)` function

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                       

    // TODO add your handling code here:

    jButton1.setIcon( loading_icon );
    microphone.startRecording()
    jButton1.setIcon( speak_icon );

    System.out.println("Start speaking. Press Ctrl-C to quit.\n");

    result = recognizer.recognize();
    if (result != null) {
         String bestfinalnofiller = result.getBestFinalResultNoFiller();
         String hypothesis = result.getBestPronunciationResult();
         String getresult = result.getBestResultNoFiller();

         System.out.println("You said: " + bestfinalnofiller + '\n');
         System.out.println("You said: " + hypothesis + '\n');
         System.out.println("You said: " + getresult + '\n');

    } else {

    } 
}
```

my result will be like:
the button icon stays the same and changes after the work is done
the system prints in while the work is going string `"start speaking..."`

`recognizer.recognize()` function:

```
public Result recognize(String referenceText) throws IllegalStateException {

    Result result = null;
    checkState(State.READY);
    try {
        setState(State.RECOGNIZING);
        result = decoder.decode(referenceText);
    } finally {
        setState(State.READY);
    }
    return result;

}
```

I tried to add:

```
SwingUtilities.invokeLater
```

but didn't work, please help me, I want to make the button changes it's icon image while the calculations ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is likely that `recognizer.recognize()` is a blocking method, that is, until it is finished, it will not return.

What this means is until the method returns, you are blocking the Event Dispatching Thread, which is responsible for, amongst other things, process paint requests.

This means until your method returns, nothing can be painted or updated (or responded to).

A simple solution would be to use a `SwinWorker`, which would allow you to set up a background process in order to perform the blocking call but also provides a number of methods synchronise any updates to the UI via the EDT

Take a closer look at [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) and [SwimgWorker](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html) for more details

Comment: but why doesn't swing fix painting the unpainted graphics before it goes to another line, is there any solution to me besides the 'SwingWorker'. thanks again

Comment: @malekh Because Swing is a single threaded framework, like most GUI frameworks.  `actionPerformed` is called within the context of the EDT, meaning that until the method exists, it can't process the next series of events (including paint events). This is just how it works.

Comment: if 'actionPerformed' is called with the context of the EDIT, is there anyway to use maybe 'mouse-click' function or 'on-release' function.

Comment: Nope, all events are delivered within the context of the Event Dispatching Thread...that's the point.  This ensures that events are processed in appropriate order and don't allow for potential race conditions or other threading issues.  Best bet, is still the `SwingWorker`

Comment: yeah and you're betting true, i tried every single possible way it all didn't work, but with 'SwingWorker', the problem is solved!